# undefined method error for instance variables in rails4 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, helper, activemodel

I was practising one of tutorials from a book. In this tutorial; all values from a few models were needed to be shown in some views. These instance variables were defined under `sidebar_values` method in `application_controller.rb`:

```
helper_method :sidebar_values

def sidebar_values
    @food_prefs = FoodPreference.all
    @food_types = FoodType.all
    @cuisines = Cuisine.all
end
```

Here is the part of the `application.html.erb`:

```
            <div class="col-lg-2">
                <div class="panel panel-primary" id="panels">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        Food Preferences
                    </div>
                    <% @food_prefs.each do |p| %> #42, error begins here
                        <p><%= p.name %></p>
                    <% end %>
                </div>
                <div class="panel panel-primary" id="panels">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        Food Types
                    </div>
                    <% @food_types.each do |t| %>
                        <p><%= t.name %></p>
                    <% end %>
                </div>
                <div class="panel panel-primary" id="panels">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        Cuisines
                    </div>
                    <% @cuisines.each do |c| %>
                        <p><%= c.name %></p>
                    <% end %>
                </div>
            </div>
```

When I was trying to call these variables in a view, it throws error like this:

```
NoMethodError - undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass:
    app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:42:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___4138475832854219665_70001190164060'
```

Values in these variables aren't `nil`, however I was unable to call these variables from any view.

Comment: Post your view `code`

Comment: At which line are you getting that error?

Comment: @Pavan 42 as question is updated

Comment: Do you actually call this method `sidebar_values`? Like a `before_filter :sidebar_values` or in your action(s)? It seems that you don't call it so it is not setting the instance variables -- Also, I don't see why you would have to make it a helper method, since these assignations (instance variables starting with `@`) are usually set in the controllers..

Comment: It is difficult to find the line 42 in the code.Can you please highlight the error line ?

Comment: @MrYoshiji according to the tutorial, nothing were done about it. just defining method, instance variables. then they were used on the view and it worked(!). FYI, first tutorial on this book: http://www.packtpub.com/rails-4-application-development-hotshot/book

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know you are following a tutorial, but I think there is something missing:

```
# application_controller.rb
before_filter :sidebar_values

def sidebar_values
  @food_prefs = FoodPreference.all
  @food_types = FoodType.all
  @cuisines = Cuisine.all
end
```

This `before_filter :sidebar_values` will call the method `sidebar_values` on each action called. You can specify only/except options to filter a little bit the affected actions:

```
before_filter :sidebar_values, except: [:login, :logout]
```

---

Also, I would use a better name for this method, something like `set_sidebar_variables` since it is setting instance variables for the sidebar.

As I explained in the comments, I don't think you need to make it a helper method, IMO `helper_method :sidebar_values` can be removed.

---

Another thing is that there is not limit on your SQL queries, you just query all of the 3 models. This is not good in long-term. What if you have hundreds of Cuisines, FoodTypes and FoodPrefs ? I would add a `.limit(x)` to prevent from this case to happen:

```
def sidebar_values
  @food_prefs = FoodPreference.limit(10)
  @food_types = FoodType.limit(10)
  @cuisines = Cuisine.all
end
```

Comment: It particularly solved the problem, variables were got but I wonder how I get variables defined in helper method.

Comment: @ekremkrc You might have to call the helper method in the view before rendering the sidebar, which would set your variables before you render the view using these variables. But it is not a best-practice at all to call Model methods in views... Even if they are called via a helper -- Its like starting to build a Car without all the required pieces, and during the construction process you ask for these missing pieces.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you are getting `undefined method 'each' for nil:NilClass:` on `<% @food_prefs.each do |p| %>` is because `@food_prefs` variable is nil. you are calling a method: `each` on a nil variable: `@food_prefs`. basically, if you open a `rails console` and query `FoodPreference.count`, it would return `zero` count. To get past this, create an instance of this class in the database so your count is no longer zero.

Or:

wrap around it an if statement. something like this:

```
<% if @food_prefs %>
  <% @food_prefs.each do |p| %> 
     <p><%= p.name %></p>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

you can remove this `if statement` later when you are sure your `@food_prefs` is no longer `nil`

How to define variables in a helper method:

though you may not need to define helper method in this case, you define them inside the files in your `Helper` folder. it's a straight forward ruby. just create methods that you can call inside your views. unlike the controller methods, you don't need the `@` symbol. methods created inside your `helpers` are available in your views.